# JavaScript - IE 9 XML textContent

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox, internet-explorer-9

The next code works well under Firefox, but IE 9 gives udnefiend as result:

```
var url = "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml";

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(event){ processRequest(event,xmlhttp); };
xmlhttp.send();

function processRequest(event,xmlhttp) {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState != 4) return;
    if(xmlhttp.status != 200) return;
    var responseXML = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    alert(responseXML.getElementsByTagName("note")[0].getElementsByTagName("to")[0].textContent);
}
```

How can I get the textContent of an XML element in IE9?

Comment: i think it's just text or textValue, but i am not that sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the value of any node from an XML DOM object, use the property

```
dom_node.nodeValue;
```

textContent is not a W3C standard recommendation. Request you to use the standard properties which are cross-browser compatible.

Comment: `textContent` is part of DOM level 3: http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#Node3-textContent